# How do I find the base angles without a vertex angle in a isosceles triangle?

Tags: geometry

How can I find the base angles in a isosceles triangle if the vertex angle is missing?
Normally, I would go: 2x + vertex angle = 180, but now even the vertex is missing, the only thing I have is a line in the middle, with 90 degree angle.

Maybe the 90 degree should be used to find one of the base angles and one of the vertex angles, any help is appreciated, thanks a lot, I am still learning this, any tips are very useful.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is find one base angle, since in an isosceles triangle, both those angles are opposite equal sides, and are therefore equal.

**Edit**: Now that I see your image, You have enough information to find *everything.*

- You can use the Pythagorean Theorem to obtain the altitude (the unknown side in the middle.)
- The vertex, B, is split into two equal angles, but you can easily find the vertex angle by first finding one of the base angles.
- You can find the base angle B by using the fact that $$\cos B =
     \dfrac{\text{Adjacent}}{\text{Hypotenuse}}\implies B =
     \cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\text{Adjacent}}{\text{Hypotenuse}}\right) = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{10.9}{25.6}\right) = 64.8$$

---

Each base angle, let's call them each of measure $x$, plus the vertex angle add up to $180$.

So if you need to solve for the vertex angle $\theta$, we have that $\theta = 180 - 2x$.

Also note, to find an angle, given none of the angles are known, *you can to use the lengths of the sides of the triangle* to solve for the base angles and/or vertex, and can use the [Law of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) to do that.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but the Q is how, I do not have the vertex angle either, I only have a 90 degree angle, I can subtract 90 degree from 180, but that would still not allow me to find the one of the base angles or the vertex angle.

Comment: I am not sure that, that is the correct answer? I looked in the back of the book, and it looks like the base angels shall equal: 64.8 degrees each. But I want to find this step by step, and not copy from the answers page in the back of the book. Thanks!

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question. You need to use the lenghths of the sides of the triangle to solve for the base angle and/or vertex.

Comment: I have the following data: H = 25.6, B = 21.8/2 = 10.9 (This is of course the adjacent)

Comment: Well, if it's an isosceles triangle, then two sides are equal! So you have all three sides to work with, which you'll need here.

Comment: hypotenuse = 25.6, B (Base), the thing is that I am not sure of how to take the next steps, if there are any tutorials or step by steps I would love to read, in addition, been watching some Khan Academy videos too, but no luck seems like I am unable to find any videos.

Comment: Look at the linked Wikipedia page on the law of cosines.

Comment: Pythagorean theorem maybe should work, I am not sure on this.

Comment: I'm not clear on the image you're working with.

Comment: There's a isosceles triangle that bisects the base i.e. an altitude, now, there are two hypotenuses each 25.6 dm, the base is 21.8 dm (or if you separate one triangle the base becomes 10.9 dm), and two 90 degree angles.

Comment: Yes, John, you can use the Pythagorean Theorem to obtain the altitude (the unknown side in the middle.) The vertex, B, is split into two equal angles. But you can find the base angle B by using the fact that $$\cos B = \dfrac{\text{Adjacent}}{\text{Hypotenuse}}\implies B = \cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\text{Adjacent}}{\text{Hypotenuse}}\right)$$

Comment: Interesting, I will try this soon and report back, thanks a lot for your effort. :)

Comment: Glad to hear back from you. Yes indeed, the image helped immensely. Please do report back!

Comment: Yes, that worked, however, is the 64.8 degrees for the vertex or the base angles? (EDIT: AFAIK from the book, there are two: 64,8 and one 50,4 degrees (I suspect the 50,4 is for vertex at the top), and that 64.8 is for the base angles because they both should equal the same, given the fact that we also have the altitude will divide the vertex i.e. 50,4 / 2 = 25,2 degrees.

Comment: That's for the base angle B. To compute the vertex, subtract $180 - 2\cdot 64.8$. Don't forget to accept the answer. I'm sorry, I was using $B$ to denote the "Base angle, not to denote the vertex.

Comment: Hmm, but I have two 90 degrees as well.

Comment: I.e. x = 180 - (90 + 64.8) = 25.2 this is correct, since the angle C must be 64,8 or ??

Comment: I was talking about the vertex of the largest triangle (the . Each of the smaller triangles also add up to 180, where the smallest angle at the top for the small triangles is $180 - 90 - 64.8$). But the only angles of the largest triangle are $64.8, 64.8, 50.4$add up to sum 180

Comment: So if we removed one of the triangles from the isosceles triangle, i.e. we now have a standalone with previous values, 90, 64.8 and C, would C then become the 25.2 degree angle?

Comment: Exactly! That's correct!

Comment: So base are 25.2?

Comment: Just trying to understand what I have achieved here, and what I have learned from this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, the base angles are both $64.8$, the vertex of the largest triangle is $50.4$, and half of that at the top is the angle $25.2.$ The line in the middle of the largest triangle divided the big triangle exactly in half.

Comment: Do you see my picture which I posted here, the x(s) actually represent the uknown angles, so if I have understood this correctly, the x = 25.2 or 64.8 ? Can you if possible explain this in detail, thanks a lot.

Comment: x = 64.8. That's what my work was calculating.

Comment: Yes, then it is as I was thinking, that you divide it etc. Nice solved and clear, I now understand it completely. Thanks a lot @amwhy.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Are you a math teacher, @amwhy?

Comment: Not currently, but I have taught both at a community college and at a university.

Comment: COOOOLL! I like this a lot, this explains your great skills. Sad that you do not have a job.

Comment: Thank you. I'm working, but right now on research. Just not currently teaching (but of course, I teach here at MSE) ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: That was quite the discsussion! :-) +1